# AWS SNS push notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

While creating a platform application when I tried to create application and push notification platform select GCM then add API key I got the following.

> Invalid parameter: Attributes Reason: Platform credentials are invalid
>   (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter;
>   Request ID: 44a04d15-c58b-5bf8-859e-0311947aac6c)

What does this mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: When you created the API server key on Google's API console, did you set any restricted IP ranges or host names?

Comment: yes i make it open for all

Comment: how do i register "registerID" of that  application in SNS console so i can send push to user .....????

Any idea or sample code ...which can guide me..

Answer (score 3):

I got exactly same error message as yours. It seems google is migrating Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to Google Cloud Messaging, and the API Key created via Credentials in API Manager of Google Cloud Platform is not working.

And here is how I get it to work.

1. Go to [Firebase Console](http://console.firebase.google.com) and import Google Cloud Project.
2. Go to Project settings on Firebase Console and you should see the Web API
   Key of your project.
3. Go back to your Google Cloud Platform, and go to Credentials of API Manager, you should see there are two API keys have been generated. Browser key (auto created by Google Service) and Server key (auto created by Google Service)
4. The Server key (auto created by Google Service) is what you need to
   use on the Amazon SNS.

Hope it can resolve your problem, and hope it is only a temporary solution that after Google done the migration, we can directly use the API key created in API Manager.

Comment: Yeah nice job. I noticed that friebase console is absolutely not stable, I had to make several refresh before I can see the console